# Will replication help stabilize the database reading service?

Tags: postgresql, performance, database-replication

I had have to redefine the description of the problem.

I have PostgreSQL cloud-based database, making 1.5M requests per day. I checked the statistics of the individual queries themselves with different variants of the extracted data. In general, the individual queries seem to be okay (they are really simple and are unlikely to delay). The problem occurs while the application is running. The application is an internet game. During one gaming session, new records (with the current state of the game) are constantly being written to the database. A lot of inserts are made at this time. The user may wish to see the history of the game at any time(while such inserts are in progress). At this point, when the writing-service is adding new records into the database, the reading-service reads the data. Such reading is very rare compared to writing, it occurs in a ratio of 1:100 (but such reading will occur more often in the future). Service ugh-read usually reads data in 0-6 seconds. Sometimes the reading time increases to over 40 or even 100 seconds. Rare jumps like 10-20 seconds would be acceptable, but I absolutely need to get rid of jumps over 40 seconds.
For this particular problem I think about replication MASTER-SLAVE (write_only-read_only)

The additional information: commentator asked about:

- Cloud service: gcp
- Service limit: limits:
  memory: 1500Mi
  cpu: 500m
- Postgres version: 10

If would be good, I could present the structure of queries and tables. Everything is written in spring.

Comment: Yes and 1% is a reading, 99% is a writing at the moment.

Comment: Well if only 1% of all requests is reading, then moving them to a different server won't really help you much. You will have to find a way to optimize the writing. But this question is way too broad for Stackoverflow.

Comment: So, do you have any advice on where I should seek help and solutions?

Comment: The [mailing lists](https://www.postgresql.org/list/) would probably be a good start. But you will have to provide much more details there as well if you want to initiate a good discussion (which it will turn into - it's not as simple as a "FAQ")

Comment: Thanks, what do you think about such post on "Database Administrators" division on "StackExchange" ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply speaking, you have to find and remove the bottleneck.

A few pointers:

- Look at the operating system and see how the I/O system and the CPU are doing.
- Reduce the number of concurrent database connections, perhaps using a connection pool.
- Employ `pg_stat_statements`  to find the statements that cause the most load.

Comment: Thank you very much I'll try this pointers. But what do you generally think about the replica idea in this case? Does it help in such situations?

Comment: That's impossible to say, because you didn't give any data points. But my intuition would be to fight the cause of the problem rather than expending money and effort on a workaround before you have understood the problem.

Comment: I edited the post and added some information because I understood my problem in a different way, I think it changes a lot. Would you please take a second look?